# how to process the buffer character-by-character in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write some elisp to process each character in the current buffer
(I know this will be a bit slow, but think it is the best way).  I do not want to use a regular expression. How to do this?

The function `buffer-string` returns the current buffer as a string. Using this could iterate over and reference/set each character. I cannot figure out how to put the result back in the buffer however.
Can someone give a example of just iterating over each character, change it in some simple way, and put the result back in the buffer?

Answer (score 7):

Use a `while` loop and `forward-char` to iterate over all characters in a buffer:

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (not (eobp))
  (let* ((current-character (char-after))
         (new-character (do-something current-character)))
    (delete-char 1)
    (insert-char new-character))
  (forward-char 1))
```

The loop moves forward one character at a time, as long as the end of the buffer (`eobp`) is not reached.

`char-after` gives you the character at the current position.  The `delete-char`/`insert-char` calls replace the old character with the new one, that results from processing the old character.

To replace the old character with multiple characters, i.e. a string, simply `insert-char` with `insert`.  `insert` puts the point *after* the newly inserted characters, so the loop will proceed with the next *unprocessed* character afterwards.

Comment: This assumes you always replace the current character with a single character. If you need to insert more text and/or insert elsewhere in the buffer, extending the code to do that should not be terribly hard. Off the top of my head, look at `save-excursion`, but other approaches could make more sense, depending on the details of your scenario.

Comment: @tripleee You don't need `save-excursion` to insert multiple characters.  You'd just `insert`, which implicitly puts the point after the newly inserted string, so the loop will proceed with the next original character afterwards.  I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Right; thanks for the update. I'm leaving my comment as it may still be useful for inserting elsewhere in the buffer.

Comment: Just want to point out explicitly to the OP that (as your solution demonstrates) you do *not* want to use `buffer-string`, work on that string, and then replace the buffer content with the resulting string.  You want to work on the text in place, in the buffer.  In Emacs, buffers are efficient to work with, and it is generally better to use them than to use strings.

Answer (score 1):

To add something to what @lunaryorn says - perhaps a part of a solution, depending on what you need, and so not just a comment:

When you process a buffer character by character, it is very commonly the case that you do not want or need to do something for **each** character, but you instead need to do something for particular characters in the buffer.

When this is the case, you often do **not** need to examine each character.  Instead, you can use functions such as these (see their doc for what they do):

- `search-forward` or `re-search-forward`, if specific characters are targeted
- `next-single-property-change`, if one or more characters with specific text properties are targeted (or perhaps `next-single-char-property-change`, if overlays are involved)
- `next-property-change`, if one or more characters any text-property change are targeted (or perhaps `next-char-property-change`, if overlays are involved)

In such cases, you iterate over buffer positions (so, over the chars at those positions), as for @lunaryorn's solution, but you use such a function to quickly skip over characters you are not interested in.  This is **much more common**, IMO, than checking each character, one by one.  But whether or not it fits your use case, I don't know.